# Custom property name on object serialization

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization

I have data bind to an object. Now I want to serialize it with a custom property name.

```
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "KLM")]
        public string ABC { get; set; } = "Test1";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NOP")]
        public string DEF { get; set; } = "Test2";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "QRS")]
        public string GHI { get; set; } = "Test3";
```

When I serialize this object I want below serialization

```
{ "KLM" : "Test1", "NOP" : "Test2", "QRS" : "Test3" }
```

instead of

```
{ "ABC" : "Test1", "DEF" : "Test2", "GHI" : "Test3" }
```

and when deserialize it with the below JSON it should work just fine

```
{ "ABC" : "1Test", "DEF" : "2Test", "GHI" : "3Test" }
```

This question might have been asked many times, but I couldn't find the appropriate answer.

Comment: You need to set the attributes separately on getter and setter to achieve different property names. i.e.- getter for serializing and setter for deserializing.

Comment: You can use DTO models to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try that:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Application.ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var j = "{ \"KLM\" : \"Test1\", \"NOP\" : \"Test2\", \"QRS\" : \"Test3\" }";

            var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJsonObject>(j);

            var s  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
        }
    }

    public class MyJsonObject
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "KLM")]
        public string ABC { get; set; } = "Test1";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NOP")]
        public string DEF { get; set; } = "Test2";

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "QRS")]
        public string GHI { get; set; } = "Test3";
    }
}
```

You might be using different tools for attributes and serialization / deserialization. In my example, you can see that I am using the Newtonsoft library. I am taking attributes and methods from this library. For example, if you use attributes from Newtonsoft and methods from System.Text.Json, it won't work the way you want.

UPD:

[image]

Isn't that what you want?

The image shows that this works both ways. If json matches attributes then it is desirialized by attributes. If json matches the names of the properties of the class, then json is deserialized by the names of the properties. This object is always desirialized by attributes.

Sorry if I still misunderstand you!

Comment: if your j becomes { "ABC" : "1Test", "DEF" : "2Test", "GHI" : "3Test" }, then you will get null values in object

Comment: deserializer will look for JSON Property Name instead of actual property name

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood you. Do you want the parameters to be filled either by attributes or by property names?

Comment: At the time of filling it should consider property name and at the time of popping out JSON it should consider attribute name, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Wait, were you able to deserialise for the output one? I have the same condition but it won't work. I have this test data. I am not able to deserialise

Comment: Yes, it works for me both ways. I am using Newtonsoft.Json v. 13.0.1. Maybe this is important.